# Is Mac required for the iOS Developer Enterprise Program?

Tags: ios, macos

Is it mandatory to buy Mac to enroll in the iOS Developer Enterprise Program?
I would like to provide a subcontractor with my distribution certificate and provisioning profile so he could produce already signed and profiled installation package for my organization. Having a Mac in my organization seems to be pointless in this scenario.

Regards!

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Looked into this a while back. It'll probably work out cheaper just to outsource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to buy a Mac to enrol, however, it's necessary to use a Mac to create the certificate and its private key, as these are created through the Keychain Access application's Certificate Assistant.

It is also necessary to use a Mac to build and sign applications.

Comment: Thank you guys, As I said, I do not want to do any development in house, so probably the cheapest Mac with the certificate creation capability is enough. Is Mac mini with OS X Lion Server OK for mentioned purposes?

Answer (score 1):

there is no Windows tools for building apps, but for enrolling you don't need Mac